# Is there Expression trees equivalent of of FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, internals, linq-expressions

Normally I'd call `Expression.New(type)`, but when a type doesn't have a parameterless constructor, that is not possible.

- How does `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()` work internally?
- Is calling `operator new()` faster than calling `FormatterServices.GetUninitializeObject()`?
- Is there an `Expressions` equivalent of `GetUninitializedObject`, or the only way to do this is using `Expression.Call` for it?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Because the new instance of the object is initialized to zero and no constructors are run, the object might not represent a state that is regarded as valid by that object. The current method should only be used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate all fields. It does not create an uninitialized string, since creating an empty instance of an immutable type serves no purpose.

So, to answer your questions:

1. I looked at the method using ILSpy, and all it does is a couple of checks, then calls a native (C++ I assume) method. I'm guessing it just allocates enough memory for the object, initializes all fields to zero/null, then returns a pointer to that object. No constructors are called.
2. Assuming the `new()` constructor does nothing, they're probably about the same.
3. No. You would have to use `Expression.Call`, which would return an `object` then if you wanted to do anything with it `Expression.Convert` to whatever type you needed the object to be.

Comment: Operator new is a lot faster since it is a JIT intrinsic and a very, very common case.